# How does scanf() reads when input is not in specified format?

Tags: c

The input and output for the following program are given below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int a=0, b=100, c=200;
scanf("%d,%d,%d",&a,&b,&c);
printf("%d %d %d\n",a,b,c);
return 0;
}
```

**Input-1:**

1,2,3

**Output-1:**

1 2 3

So the first output is correct and as expected.

**Input-2:**

1 2 3

**Output-2:**

1 100 200

Here it reads first integer correctly but I am not able to understand, how the `scanf()` reads the data after first integer when we are not giving the input in specified format?

As values entered after first integer are not assigned to any variables, What happens to those values?

Are they written on some random memory locations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Here it reads first integer correctly but I am not able to understand,
>   how the scanf() reads the data after first integer when we are not
>   giving the input in specified format?

`scanf` stops at the first mismatch and leaves the rest of the target objects untouched. You can inspect the return value to determine how many "items" `scanf` matched.

> As values entered after first integer are not assigned to any
>   variables, What happens to those values?

The unmatched data is left in the input buffer, available for a subsequent read using `scanf`, `fgets` etc.

---

> I used getchar() and putchar() after last printf() statement in the
>   program but nothing was read.

Strange. You should be able to get away with something like:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF)
    putchar(ch);
```

Comment: I am fully satisfied with your first answer but can you show how to read that data which is left? I used getchar() and putchar() after last printf() statement in the program but nothing was read.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR answer: It doesn't. It stops reading.

To clarify, `input is not in specified format` is a *matching failure* for `scanf()`. That is why it's always recommended to check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure *all* the input items got *scanned* successfully.

In the second input scenario, the `scanf()` has failed to scan *all* the input parameters because of the format mismatch of *expected* and *received* inputs [and you have no idea of that]. Only the value of `a` has been scanned successfully, and reflected.

[Just for sake of completeness of the answer]:

After the input value of `a`, due to the absence of a `,` in the input, mismatch happened and `scanf()` stopped scanning, returning a value of `1`. That's why, `b` and `c` prints out their initial values.

Comment: Isn't it because of the commas in the scanf? Because if you remove those it works

Comment: @Rizier123 yeah, the supplied format has to _exactly_ match the supplied input.

Comment: `scanf()` will return the number of integers read successfully and in this case it is 1, so how to check it's an error?

Comment: in case of _success_, it should be 3, not 1. also, its not `number of integers`, rather, `number of input items scanned successfully`