# Loop that only accepts numbers in between a certain interval

Tags: c, integer, do-while

I have a do-while loop that is supposed to only accept numbers between [0;26], integers, not unsigned. But when I type a letter or another character that is not a number, it accepts and initializes my integer as 0. Here is the code:

```
int cifra;
do
{
    printf("Insira a cifra a utilizar no intervalo [0;26]: ");
    scanf("%d", &cifra);
 }while(cifra > 26 || cifra < 0);
```

Comment: There have to be thousands of duplicates to this, but I'm to lazy to try and find a good one... So the problem is that if the `scanf` format specifier doesn't match the input, it doesn't remove the failing input from the buffer. So next iteration of the loop it will read the very same input as before. And again and again and again... I recommend you [read *lines*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and then use `sscanf` to parse the line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does scanf() reads when input is not in specified format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961609/how-does-scanf-reads-when-input-is-not-in-specified-format)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use scanf you must do something like this:
Please see the comments.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int c,cifra,result;
    do
        {
            printf("Insira a cifra a utilizar no intervalo [0;26]: ");
            result=scanf("%d", &cifra); //on successful read result must be one.(one element)
            while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' ) ; //empty the buffer
        }
    while(cifra > 26 || cifra < 0|| result!=1);

    printf("You did it\n");
}
```

Comment: It works thank you. But explain me something so I really understands this: why does getchar() = c has to be different than EOF? Isn't that associated with files?

Comment: @Luis Gaspar about EOF() : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358728/end-of-file-eof-in-c

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. But meanwhile I could reduce the code and make it work with only
    while(getchar() != '\n');

Comment: Still keeping the result=scanf and while result != 1 part

Comment: `cifra > 26 || cifra < 0|| result!=1` is better as `result!=1 || cifra > 26 || cifra < 0` as accessing `cifra` before it is assigned is undefined behavior.